# Python and Secpay (paypoint) xml-rpc call

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have the next code somewhere in Pyramid application

```
import xmlrpclib

....

@view_config(route_name='api-paypoint', renderer='string')
def api_paypoint(request):
    call_data = ["mid", "password", "name"]
    api_server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://www.secpay.com/secxmlrpc/make_call')
    response = api_server.SECVPN.validateCardFull(call_data)
    print response
    return {}
```

What I'm trying is to call Secpay API (here's JAVA's example http://www.paypoint.net/support/gateway/soap-xmlrpc/xmlrpc-java/ )
I'm getting the next error:

```
Exception Value: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.secpay.secvpn.SECVPN.validateCardFull(java.util.Vector)'>
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. I was trying to pass  to api_server.SECVPN.validateCardFull() which is wrong. This should be changed to

```
api_server.SECVPN.validateCardFull('mid', 'password', 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling with the wrong number of arguments, and the java serverside can't find a method matching that signature. If you call with 14 strings the exception changes (something about the serverside failing to encode a null).

```
proxy.SECVPN.validateCardFull("","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
```